# Loaded Data and Multitasking?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am writing a utility where data for games is written to disk at various stages throughout the game (including, but not relying on when the app exits). My question is currently I am doing my initial load using `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` but was curious about what happens when the application goes into the background / is suspended etc. Currently I am assuming that all my loaded data will hang around and I only need to do a load when the application initially loads. Is this the case or can iOS flush my stored data and I should look at checking if a load is needed in say `applicationWillEnterForeground:`

Also its a pretty small amount of data (20 small NSArray objects) but I guess I could always save and clear the data store when I get `applicationDidEnterBackground:` and reload on `applicationWillEnterForeground:` Or given that its just a small about of data would I be better to just leave it resident at all times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save your state when you get applicationWillResignActive:

That happens when you go into the background, or get a phone call, or several other interruptions occur.  This is a better place than applicationDidEnterBackground: since that doesn't get called in devices running pre iOS 4.0 (which only matters if you support ios < 4).

Once your app goes into the background or is interrupted it can get killed without any warning, so this is your last sure chance to save/flush state data.

There is no need to reload data when you return to the foreground.  If that happens, your app is still in memory with its data still there (except possibly view(s) may have been unloaded)

Comment: Perfect, the bit at the end about data being unloaded (like views can be) or staying in memory was what I was after. Also applicationWillResignActive is a good suggestion pre iOS4 devices.

Answer (score 1):

I advice that you always save your in-memory data when your app moves to the background. When in the background iOS may terminate your app when it needs the memory and you won't be notified when that happens.

Comment: Ok thanks, as far as loading goes I don't need to check when I exit the background (as the application did not terminate and the apps data is still in memory) just when the application loads, either originally or after its been terminated by the system? –